# Eigenvectors of a Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, python, hermitian-matrices

A Hermitian matrix is a complex square matrix which is equal to its conjugate transpose. Its matrix elements fulfil following condition:

$$a_{ij} = \bar{a}_{ji}$$

Everytime, I compute eigenvectors of a Hermitian matrix using Python, the first coefficient of the eigenvector is a pure real number. Is this an attribute of Hermitian matrices?

I attach a code snippet to generate a Hermitian matrix, compute its eigenvectors and print the eigenvector corresponding to the lowest eigenvalue.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
N = 5   # Set size of a matrix
# Generate real part of the matrix at first
real_matrix = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=(N,N))
real_matrix = (real_matrix + real_matrix.T)/2
# Generate imaginary part of the matrix
imaginary_matrix = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=(N,N))
imaginary_matrix = (imaginary_matrix + imaginary_matrix.T)/2
imaginary_matrix = imaginary_matrix.astype(complex) * 1j
for row in range(N):
    for column in range(row,N):
        if row == column:
            imaginary_matrix[row][column] = 0.0
        else:
            imaginary_matrix[row][column] *= -1
# Combine real and imaginary part
matrix = real_matrix + imaginary_matrix
# Compute and print eigenvector
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = LA.eigh(matrix)
print(eigenvectors[:,0])
```

This question was originally posted on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50141450/eigenvectors-of-a-hermitian-matrix).

Comment: I know that SO told you to post here, but this is really a python question.  Any scalar multiple of any eigenvector is again an eigenvector (with the same eigenvalue), so whatever python's output is, it could be multiplied by, e.g., $i$ and it would still be correct.  So it comes down to how function calls used in your code chose to represent the eigenvectors.

Comment: P.S.  [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1162-L1294) is the source code for LA.eigh().  You can trace through there how that function decides to represent the eigenvectors.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the first coefficient of an eigenvector is, since if $v$ is an eigenvector, then so is $zv$ for any complex number $z$. It's not meaningful to look very hard at the individual coefficents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting my comment as an answer:

Any scalar multiple of any eigenvector is again an eigenvector (with the same eigenvalue), so whatever your code's output (for representing the eigenvectors) is, it could be multiplied by, e.g., $i$ and it would still be correct. So it comes down to how function calls used in your code chose to represent the eigenvectors.

See [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1162-L1294) is the source code for LA.eigh(), which is used in your code to get the eigenvectors.